# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jwSlider' (Anonymous Function)

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, typeerror

The page is: http://www.solopresswebdesign.com/design/challenge4life/

The slider was working but now it seems to of stopped and throws the error below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jwSlider' (Anonymous Function)
```

I've checked all files and they link correctly and I've read through here for answers but I can't seem to get it fixed, am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance.